# Pull request to julia package

Tags: git, github, julia

I'm learning some github features and I want to propose a pull request for a
couple of bugs that I have found in one of the julia packages. The thing that
confuses me a bit is that if I am on my local julia/ I don't see my local branch
where I submitted the bug-fixes. If I go to my ~/.julia/ there I can see my local
branch.

In any case, which `git remote add upstream <url>` should I use in order to ask
for a pull request ticket?

Comment: I usually fork the repo and continue from there as described on [GitHub's "Fork a Repo"](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) webpage.

Comment: Yeah I was also checking the docs you suggest. But I have already a clone on my machine and I would to link it with my fork at github.

Comment: So on your local machine you have a clone of the original repo, not your forked repo?

Comment: that's right, now I don't know how to tell github, hey look at here, I have already a clone and a local branch.

Comment: Looks like you need some git-foo(TM).  I've never done that, but first I'd backup everything, then add _my_ GitHub repo as a remote repo, and push my local branch to it.  Fingers crossed that might work and then submitting a PR request is easy.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually really really easy with Julia.

1. Ensure that JSON is installed, and that git is properly configured (You can enter shell mode from Julia by typing `;` at the beginning of a line)

   ```
   julia> Pkg.add("JSON")
   shell> git config --global user.name "FULL NAME"
   shell> git config --global user.email "EMAIL"
   shell> git config --global github.user "USERNAME"
   ```

Note that the email you provide will be public.

2. Do a checkout to ensure that you are on master (your PR might not apply cleanly if you base it on the last released version)

   ```
   julia> Pkg.checkout("PackageName")
   # or
   shell> cd ~/.julia/v0.3/PackageName
   shell> git checkout master
   ```
3. Do your changes and commit them

   ```
   $ edit ~/.julia/v0.3/PackageName/src/PackageName.jl
   $ git commit
   ```
4. Run `Pkg.submit("PackageName")`

   ```
   julia> Pkg.submit("PackageName")
   ```

Then a web browser will open with the new pull request ready to be sendt ;)

Comment: If he already has an edited local branch, how would you recommend he submit a PR without having to re-edit?  Merge his branch?

Comment: `Pkg.checkout` shows an error `ERROR: UndefVarError: checkout not defined`.

Comment: My answer was for Julia 0.3. The package manager in Julia has been rewritten since. Now you should use something like Pkg.develop or `] dev ...` to create pull requests. See https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/managing-packages/#Developing-packages-1